# Firebase: TypeError: firebase.firestore is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following the example at https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

So I have this in my index.html

```
<body>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Firebase -->
<script src="./firebase-init.js"></script>
</body>
```

and this in firebase-init.js

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ...
    authDomain: ...
    databaseURL: ...
    ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
var app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Firestore
var db = firebase.firestore();
// also tried: 
// var db = firebase.firestore(app);
// var db = app.firestore();
```

And yet whenever I try to load the page I get `TypeError: firebase.firestore is not a function`

This seems so trivial but I cannot get access to the firestore

Comment: Why do you have var db = app.firestore() as a comment? Did you try it?

Comment: yes, various permutations based on ideas in the docs, but always the same end result

Comment: Any reason why you've chosen not to put `defer` in your firebase-init.js include?  Seems like you'd want it to execute in serial with the other Firebase scripts so everything gets executed in the same order, predictably.

Comment: aha - that seems to be the issue. Adding a defer helped, but ran into issues with the rest of my code; removing them all seems to take me forward even further

Comment: @DenzDacs what about react native people who are getting the same error ??

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adding a defer here?

```
<script defer src="./init-firebase.js"></script>
```

Based on documentation I would assume that you should do this.

Comment: where to add this defer??? can you describe it please.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is with the new version.
Try using a older version of Firebase

`npm install firebase@8.10.0 --save`

Answer (score 0):

You have to import:

```
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
```

While initializing:

```
const db = getFirestore(app);
```